# Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10 Dual boot doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, 19.04

I installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode then installed Ubuntu 19.04 in a partition making (/, /swap, /boot, /home) partitions it installed perfectly.

But when I restarted my laptop Windows started automatically, and you know the loop continues.

I have used boot-repair before to solve such problems but it's not working this time so I am posting the report here,can anyone please help
[boot-repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9Cv7Knwqsn/)

Comment: How you boot install/repair media is then how it installs or fixes system. You installed Windows in UEFI boot mode but Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. With new versions of Ubuntu on desktop you usually do not need /boot partition and now a swap file is used. Start over, use Something Else, and just install / & /home partitions. Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: The swap partition is passé ; ever since 17.10, the kernel's been fast enough to make the swap file as fast as the swap partition, and since it's so much easier to scale up/down a swap file than a swap partition, the swap file is the default nowadays. You don't need a swap partition, and it's one more thing to make your life complex.